# Make the same selection of product measurements in the cart appear on the checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

This code multiplies the measures of the product and in the cart everything appears well, but on the payment page it simplifies it too much and I need them to appear on the payment page exactly as they appear in the cart.

What can I do to display the result on the checkout page?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'change_cart_item_displayed_quantity', 10, 3 );
function change_cart_item_displayed_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    $escribiunidades = 0;   

    $posareacubierta = strpos($cart_item['data'], "_area");
    $areacubierta = substr($cart_item['data'],$posareacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace("\"","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace("area","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace("value","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace(",","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace("_","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace(":","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace("]","", $areacubierta);
    $areacubierta = str_replace("}","", $areacubierta);
    if (is_numeric($areacubierta)) {
        $areacubierta = $cart_item['quantity'] * $areacubierta;
        $product_quantity =  $product_quantity . " <font style='font-size:15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px;'>CAJA(S)</font><br><font style='font-size:15px;'>(Total: " . number_format($areacubierta,2) . " m2)</font>";

        $escribiunidades = 1;
    }

    $poswidth = strpos($cart_item['data'], "width");
    $posheight = strpos($cart_item['data'], "height");
    $areamaterial = substr($cart_item['data'],$poswidth,($posheight-$poswidth));
    $areamaterial = str_replace("\"","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace("width","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace("value","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace(",","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace("_","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace(":","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace("]","", $areamaterial);
    $areamaterial = str_replace("}","", $areamaterial);

    if (is_numeric($areamaterial) && $escribiunidades == 0) {
        $areamaterial = $cart_item['quantity'] * $areamaterial;
        $product_quantity =  $product_quantity . "<font style='font-size:15px; margin-left:-25px; float:center !important;'>METRO(S) LINEAL(ES)</font><br><font style='font-size:15px;'>(Total: " . number_format($areamaterial,2) . " m2)</font>";

        $escribiunidades = 1;
    }   


    return $product_quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To answer your question, to display this on the checkout page, you can use the `woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity` hook

```php
// Display in checkout
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) { 

    // Do some magic...

    return $item_qty;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
```

---

- Since I notice that you use a lot of different string functions in your current code, in this answer I show a simple representation of how to obtain the width and height of a product as a numerical value. I believe this is also the intention in your original code. By forumulating my answer differently I believe you can rewrite your original code in a simple way

```php
// Display in checkout
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) { 

    // Get width & height
    $poswidth = (int) $cart_item['data']->get_width();
    $posheight = (int) $cart_item['data']->get_height();
    
    // Do a certain calculation
    $areamaterial = $poswidth * $posheight;

    // Condition
    if ( is_numeric( $areamaterial ) ) {
        $areamaterial = $cart_item['quantity'] * $areamaterial;

        // Notice the use of .= opposite =
        // This is adding to versus overwriting the original value
        $item_qty .= '<span style="display:block">METRO(S) LINEAL(ES) Total: "' . number_format( $areamaterial, 2 ) . '" m2)</span>';
    }

    return $item_qty;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: this is almost solved but the measurements are not shown on the checkout page, what could be wrong? https://inovaspacio.becomingweb.com/producto/loseta-vinilica-duela-tao-1-5mm/

Comment: The hook seems to work anyway, otherwise it will be a matter of debugging (maybe a plugin that influences this), the reason for this is not visible via a url as a visitor to the website